# How do I debootstrap on a local repository

Tags: apt, debootstrap, apt-mirror

I have a local Ubuntu repository generated with apt-mirror. Can I use this with debootstrap?

```
deb http://myrepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://myrepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://myrepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted multiverse universe
```

debootstrap --arch=amd64 precise chroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autsch - rtfm helped:
in my case I would use

```
debootstrap --arch=amd64 precise chroot http://myrepo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```